# How to get highest revenue between two tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables, how would I get the lifetime earnings value if royalty value is dependent on preferred royalties being higher or lesser than standard royalties?

Would this be a case of using SELECT IF?

Also, how would I get their average earnings per year, based on the date of their first published work until today?

Assumption : An author always receives the greatest of either their preferred royalties, or the publisher’s standard royalties.

My current query is way off because it doesn't account for which source of royalty it would pick between preferred or standard. I'm not sure which Select statement to use for that.

Current SQL Fiddle
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7afcd23342ffb024a2a7f2d2a270d0c1

```
**author**
id*
first_name
last_name
date_of_birth
preferred_royalties

**book**
id*
name
date_published
msrp
copies_sold
author_id
publisher_id

**publisher**
id*
name
standard_royalties
```

This is what I came up with but I know it's wrong.

```
SELECT
  author.first_name,
  author.last_name,
  (SELECT
    SUM (
      author.preferred_royalties * book.copies_sold
    ) AS lifetime earnings
  FROM
    author
    RIGHT JOIN book
      ON author.id = book.author_id)
  (SELECT
    SUM (
      (
        author.preferred_royalties * book.copies_sold
      ) / diffdate (yy, book.date_published, getdate ()) AS average earnings per YEAR FROM author
      RIGHT JOIN book
        ON author.id = book.author_id
    )
  FROM
    author
    RIGHT JOIN book
      ON author.id = book.author_id
  GROUP BY book.author_id
```

Comment: Pls see the following guidance to improve your question: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please include some sample data and expected results by editing your question. Maybe even create a [fiddle example data](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0) and include a link. Suggest using [GREATEST](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest). Keep average earnings as as separate question.

Comment: Could you please describe *how* you current query is wrong?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really make this much clearer.

Comment: My current query is way off because it doesn't account for which source of royalty it would pick between preferred or standard. I'm not sure which Select statement to use for that.

Comment: Unfortunately this is only based off the three tables I have :(

Comment: A little advice, start with `SELECT * FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.col1=table2.col JOIN table3 ON table2.col1=table3.col1` first. See everything then decide what to keep and add operation in between

Comment: Here, I prepared a fiddle for you https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=38a2c32648545f0eff52859732ffeafb . You can edit it to add more info and try your query there. Once you click 'Run', it will generate a new fiddle link. Copy that link and [paste it into your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65911554/edit)

Comment: Thanks fadlikidd, I pasted it into my question! I appreciate the help!

Comment: I think you need to add more details in `book` table. It seems to me that the table will have similar book name and id repeated with different `published_date`. That's because you're calculating AVG per year but it seems like you're taking the date difference between `published_date` and a certain date, maybe today's date for example. Can you replace the inserted values in the fiddle with a few of your table data? Just enough to reflect on how the data is being stored in those tables

Comment: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=38788d51c853b113bdf3676252b94f81) with greatest by amount in calendar years. If there was a `start_date`/`engagement_date` in the author table this would be fairly easy to base on that date.

Comment: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=80f8152fb9208207e6cdd6f179e1601e) is this what you want with the amount based on year since first published?

Comment: The table data, I unfortunately don't have access to at the moment, so I'm trying to build the query in theory.- fadlikidd

Comment: I'm assuming that it would be the current date minus date of first publish - convert to years in difference. From there lifetime savings divided by that. - Danblack

Comment: pls provide your expected results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's much easier to understand if we have example data at least but I guess this idea is a start:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, 
       SUM(EarningByBook) AS 'Lifetime Earning', 
       SUM(copies_sold) AS 'Copies Sold',
       SUM(years) as 'Total Years',
       SUM(EarningByBook)/SUM(Years) AS 'AVG earning per year'
FROM
(SELECT first_name, last_name,
       CASE WHEN preferred_royalties > standard_royalties
                THEN preferred_royalties*copies_sold
                ELSE standard_royalties*copies_sold END 
       AS 'EarningByBook', 
       copies_sold ,
       YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(date_published) Years
FROM author A 
JOIN book B ON A.id=B.author_id 
JOIN publisher P ON B.publisher_id=P.id) V
GROUP BY 
 first_name, last_name;
```

What I can understand from your question is first you want to calculate earnings based on whichever value is greater between `preferred_royalties` and `standard_royalties`. Hence, the base query I did is the following:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name,
       /*here*/
       CASE WHEN preferred_royalties > standard_royalties
                THEN preferred_royalties*copies_sold
                ELSE standard_royalties*copies_sold END 
       AS 'EarningByBook', 
       /**/
       copies_sold ,
       YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(date_published) Years
FROM author A 
JOIN book B ON A.id=B.author_id 
JOIN publisher P ON B.publisher_id=P.id
```

So, `CASE` expression is picking between whichever greater and multiply it with copies_sold. I think that's quite straight forward. Then each of the book I've calculated year differences using direct subtraction of year `YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(date_published)`. Once that done, I make it as a sub-query then do the calculation.

[Here is the updated fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b7cf8a648cd712244de18b3d842c132b).